# Patterns / Ideas / Experiences for making DAL extensible

Tags: .net, entity-framework, architecture, data-access-layer, asp.net-web-api

I've been tasked with the fairly daunting task of designing an application with a multi-tenant (SaaS) server-client architecture. I've thought about the server's internal architecture for a while now, and here's what I have:

I'd like to make the server have a WebAPI implementation in either WCF or MVC4.

The server would have a plugin-based architecture, using MEF as the orchestrator. Because of the application having some requirements to change the business logic based on tenant requirements I'm thinking of doing it like this. More specifically, I would have a class/feature, which I export with MEF, and in the class, I would be able to add a metadata attribute for the WebAPI route in which the it would be hosted. Obviously, plugins might need to be extended in certain cases or maybe even used by other plugins exlusively, in which case they'd have no route.

My main problem with the server at this point is, that I've thought about the plugin-architecture in a way, that a plugin should be able to handle all the things that the plugin needs. So in terms of persistence, if a new plugin is developed, I should be able to write some code in the plugin, which would then be maybe executed by the DAL to provide persistence to the plugin's data. I do not want the plugin going past the DAL in any situation and go touch the database, seeing as the constraint for multi-tenancy and access needs to come from somewhere. In essence, I'm lost how I would optionally have the capability of defining some persistence in my plugins, if say the DAL operates on EF. I've thought about putting something like "CreatePersistentStorage(tenant)" into a plugin's interface, giving complete control to the plugin over creating a table. I believe Orchard does something like this but in a much more robust way.

I need help in how I would achieve a DAL which can be extended inside a plugin. The DAL has to have control of the final creation, so the plugin's data tables are created under the right tenant.

Maybe EF isn't the way to go? Comments / experiences on what you think would be appreciated. Also would you go WCF WebAPI or ASP.NET WebAPI at this time?

Best regards,
Lari

Comment: Just a tip: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx explains different ways of modeling a database for multi-tenant environments (and extending it per tenant).

Comment: I stumbled on that article also and based on it I'd go with the Shared Database, Separate Schemas-approach. Here's an article I found with that sort of approach implemented with EF: http://romiller.com/2011/05/23/ef-4-1-multi-tenant-with-code-first/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I have at the moment, it delivers on multi tenancy, it delivers on plugins - cleanliness/elegance not so much.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, DbCompiledModel> modelCache = 
               new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DbCompiledModel>();

    private Context(DbCompiledModel model) : base(model)
    {
    }

    public static Context Create(string tenantSchema)
    {
        var compiledModel = modelCache.GetOrAdd(
            tenantSchema,
            t =>
                {
                    var providerInfo = 
                        new DbProviderInfo("System.Data.SqlClient", "2008");
                    var modelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder();

                    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();

                    foreach (var plugin in ServiceLocator
                        .Current
                        .GetAllInstances<IPlugin>().ToList())
                    {
                        plugin.SetupPersistence(modelBuilder,tenantSchema);
                    }

                    var model = modelBuilder.Build(providerInfo);
                    return model.Compile();
                });

        return new Context(compiledModel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the database and/or tables for a new tenant
    /// </summary>
    public static void ProvisionTenant(string tenantSchema)
    {
        using (var ctx = Create(tenantSchema))
        {
            if (!ctx.Database.Exists())
            {
                ctx.Database.Create();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    var createScript = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .CreateDatabaseScript();
                    ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(createScript);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tenant already exists.");        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what a plugin might look like:

```
[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
public class Class2 : IPlugin
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lol { get; set; }

    public void SetupPersistence(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, string tenantSchema)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Class2>().ToTable("Keke", tenantSchema);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Class2>().HasKey(i => i.Id);
    }
}
```

And here's how you might use these:

```
    Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);

    Context.ProvisionTenant("personal");
    Context.ProvisionTenant("work");

    using (var db = Context.Create("personal"))
    {
        db.Set<Class2>().Add(new Class2 { Name = "Keke" });
        db.SaveChanges();
        foreach (var d in db.Set<Class2>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.Name);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

I'm using CommonServiceLocator to keep my MEF reference.

Now, this has several problems:

- A plugin has control over the table name, and also setting the schema name to the table - I have no idea how I would take control of this on the API side. I could wrap the whole EF api inside another class, but that seems like a lot of trouble just to make one function work like I want it to.
- The point of this is to have a plugin-extensible database layer, and the point of extendability, is to be ready for changes that will happen in the future, currently my implementation falls short on the change part, because there is no way to handle migrations inside plugins.
- It's terrible.

Any input is appreciated on how to handle migrations, or how to explicitly define table names for plugins from the context.